# How to define the type of a custom leaflet control

Tags: typescript, leaflet

When looking through the type definitions from `@types/leaflet` you can see custom controls defined similar to:

```
export namespace Control {
    ...
    class Zoom extends Control {
        constructor(options?: ZoomOptions);
        options: ZoomOptions;
    }
    ...
}
```

However, when creating your custom control through:

```
declare module 'leaflet' {
    namespace Control {
        class CustomControl extends Control {
            constructor(options: CustomOptions);
        }
    }
    namespace control {
        function customControl(options: CustomOptions): Control.CustomControl;
    }
}

L.Control.CustomControl = L.Control.extend({
    ...
});
```

throws a typescript error:

`Type '(new (...args: any[]) => any) & typeof Class' is missing the following properties from type 'typeof CustomControl': Zoom, Attribution, Layers, Scale, and 6 more.`

This seems to happen because the namespace and class `Control` go through Typescript's Declaration Merging. This causes `CustomControl` to require properties from the namespace rather than just the class.

Is there a way to fix this or circumvent it without forcing type `any`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We need to add more typings for method "extend".

Insert this code before your control  declaration

```
declare module 'leaflet' {
  namespace Control {
    function extend(props: any): {new(...args: any[]): any} & typeof Control;
  }
}
```

With members

```
declare module 'leaflet' {
  namespace Control {

    function extend<T extends Object>(props: T): {new(...args: any[]): T} & typeof Control;
  }
}
```

You can add same declaration for Handler

Comment: I've fixed the issue in @types/leaflet@1.4.5, so you no need a hack any more.